# Importing data incrementally from RDBMS to hive/hadoop using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, hadoop2

I have an oracle database and need to import data to a hive table. The daily import data size would be around 1 GB. What would be the better approach?

If I import each day data as a partition, how can the updated values be handled?

For example, if I imported today's data as a partition and for the next day there are some fields that are updated with the new values.

Using `--lastmodified` we can get the values but where we need to send the updated values to the new partition or to the old (already existing) partition?

If I send to the new partition, then the data is duplicated.
If I want to send to the already existing partition, how we can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Your only option is to override the entire existing partition with 'INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE...'.
Question is - how far back are you going to be constantly updating the data?
I think of 3 approaches u can consider:

- Decide on a threshold for 'fresh' data. for example '14 days backwards' or '1 month backwards'.
  Then each day you are running the job, you override partitions  (only the ones which have updated values) backwards, until  the threshold decided.
  With ~1 GB a day it should be feasible.
  All the data from before your decided time is not guranteed to be 100% correct.
  This scenario could be relevant if you know the fields can only be changed a certain time window after they were initially set.
- Make your Hive table compatible with ACID transactions, thus allowing updates on the table.
  Split your daily job to 2 tasks: the new data being written for the run day. the updated data that you need to run backwards. the sqoop will be responsible for the new data. take care of the updated data 'manually' (some script that generates the update statements)
- Don't use partitions based on time. maybe dynamic partitioning is more suitable for your use case.It depends on the nature of the data being handled.

Comment: Thankyou Belostoky, can you please elobarate on how the problem is solved using Dynamic partition.

Comment: If you are not partitioning on date, but rather on some other field which has bounded set of values (e.g. countries/device_type/network_type), you can use the syntax: INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE your_table PARTITION(part1, part2) ... see: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-Dynamic-PartitionInsert